# How do I deactivate the dialog that appears when you hold a number key pressed?

Tags: text-input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to turn off the iOS-style character picker menu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20618/how-to-turn-off-the-ios-style-character-picker-menu)

When I am writing and I hold number pressed, as when you write the number 9999999999, a dialog appears.

It ask me wether I want to write 9ª or 9º. I want none of them, I just want to write the number.

This is very annoying, how can I deactivate this behaviour altogether?

Comment: Are you on Lion? Is this the feature whereby if you hold down 'e', for example, it pops up a dialog that lets you pick accented versions of 'e'? [There's a possible answer in this question.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/20618/8823)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need re-enable key repeat for this context menu to go away. It'll affect character keys as well as number keys.

1. Open Terminal.app
2. Enter the following to turn this context menu feature off and reenable the old key repeat behaviour: `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

And you're done. Holding down any key now should repeat that key in the text entry window instead of calling up that context menu to select alternate characters.

To turn the context menu feature back on enter: `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true` instead.